# SOAP MTOM/XOP Support in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, mtom, xop

I want to create a Web Service in PHP, which can support `MTOM/XOP`. My Webservice Processing function shpuld be able to extract the attachment. As I googled I could find only `WSF(Web Service Framework)` as an answer.

Is there any alternatives? I'm new to this MTOM/XOP thing. Currently I use `NuSoap` but it dont support MTOM/XOP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch to support mtom, it might need tweaking for the full mtom spec

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/forums/forum/193578/topic/3917337